# Download Prompt (IE7) on locked machine

Tags: windows, automation, download

I'm using an OpenSpan automation to retrieve invoice pdfs from a company webpage. When the automation reaches the page where href links are clicked to retrieve the invoices, the standard IE prompt comes up (Open/Save/Cancel). The automation clicks save and assigns a filename.
The automation has been put on a virtual machine which is not to be constantly monitored. The issue is here, where the prompt does not come up (or at the very least is not manipulated?!) when a user is not logged in to the machine. The automation resumes immediately upon a user logging in.
I need to know how to manipulate (click "Save" on) this prompt, or allow it to show up openspan can do something with it, despite no one being logged in.
i know an FTP would be a much better solution, but I don't believe that's possible. I would assume this is some simple Windows setting I've overlooked, but any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you think you can't use FTP? What about a batch script, using something like [`wget`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)? It seems like you're looking for a solution to the wrong problem.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a Virtual Machine, you could make it so the user is always logged in, possibly by suspending it or hibernating only, within the machine.